# Repeated frames in image sequence render

Tags: rendering, physics, image

While rendering an image sequence in blender I encountered a problem: the sequence outputs as a series of repeated frames. Trick is that the frame is of a stationary ball and chain that is supposed to be a swinging rigid body. The only correct frame is the first one, after that it breaks and starts repeating. I'm not sure if this is a physics issue or a render error, but any help would be much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Have you baked your physics simulation?

Comment: I have not baked it yet! Didn't know that was a necessary step. Thank you!

Comment: If you want to render it, it is usually necessary.